# "msg": "not a valid RSA private key file"

Tags: ios, networking, command-line-interface

I am having issues with the RSA keys when running network_cli for ios.

I am receiving the following error by ansible-playbook:

```
fatal: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "not a valid RSA private key file"
```

(yml header)

```
- hosts: [HOSTS]
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: network_cli
```

(hosts vars)

```
[HOSTS:vars]
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/root/.ssh/id_rsa
ansible_ssh_host_keyauto_add=yes
```

More error details:

The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/ansible-connection", line 106, in start
    self.connection._connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/network_cli.py", line 307, in _connect
    ssh = self.paramiko_conn._connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py", line 249, in _connect
    self.ssh = SSH_CONNECTION_CACHE[cache_key] = self._connect_uncached()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/paramiko_ssh.py", line 365, in _connect_uncached
    raise AnsibleConnectionFailure(msg)
AnsibleConnectionFailure: not a valid RSA private key file

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue?  I am having the same one.


# ansible --version
ansible 2.7.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:27:34) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]